# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'trim' in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have following function

```
add(playload) {
    return this.http.post(`/api/v1/cards.json`, { text: trim(playload) });
}
```

It output following.

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'trim'.
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax of using `trim` is `string.trim()` where `string` is any string value in which you want to trim the whitespaces. So. you need to use `payload.trim()` like this, (and not `trim(payload)`)

```
add(playload) {
    return this.http.post(`/api/v1/cards.json`, { text: playload.trim() });
}
```